# What is the necessity of wave packet in studying matter wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, scattering

I am new to this realm of physics. I have literally understood the matter wave, wave function; read the trapped electron in an infinite potential-well. But what I didn't understand is the concept of [wave packet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet), the term which I faced many a times. Why is it necessary? What let the use of it? Plz help me explaining the concept of wave packet.

Comment: I hope you realize that there exist not "matter waves", but the solutions of the S equation describe probabilities of finding a particle at an x,y,z point at time t. The probability is wavelike, i.e. has maxima and minima, not the matter composing the particle.  If it is a composite particle, the probability describes its center of masss probable location.

Comment: @anna v: Sir, I've read many answers of yours of some relevant questions; from that I inferred that electron doesn't become wave & later switch to particle. . . One thing I want to know , sir, that if this wave is a probability distribution function . . .

Comment: , how can it has any physical existance? It is purely mathematical. And its square at a certain co-ordinate gives the probability of finding the electron; then doesn't the wave is switching to the particle, which I deem as a misconception above? Electron is neither particle nor wave, then why does the wave provides probability that "the particle" can be found here?? Confused!

Comment: At the microscopic level of "particles" we  have to understand that they are not the classical particles. Electrons have a physical existence, we can see their spot at single electron double slit experiments. We call "existence" when we can repeatedly observe a phenomenon. To explain their behavior we use mathematics. This is what we do in physics even classically (position of  orbiting satellites are explained with mathematics of classical physics). Observations of electrons and other particles show that different mathematics are needed. Nature works with probabilities at that level.

Comment: Why is not answered by physics at a final state, why does the apple fall? because of gravity. Why gravity? because that is the mathematical theory that contains all our observations on falling objects. That is the way that nature behaves, no further why can have a physics answer. Only metaphysics like "God made it so".

Comment: So, sir, by particle, we mean to say the **existance**? Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: well, in a sense, yes. Something exists and interacts. We can describe what it is doing with mathematics but not answer "why" it  exists. The mathematical models can answer a lot of "why"  showing "how" from A one goes to B, until they reach the basic assumptions, which have to be postulated, like the axioms of mathematics. then it becomes metaphysics.

Answer (score 3):

The time evolution of wave function is dictated by the Schrödinger equation, as you surely well know. Let's take the simple free particle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with mass $1/2$ and $\hbar=1$):
$$i\partial_t \psi(t,x)=-\Delta_x \psi(t,x)\; ;$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator (i.e. $\partial_x^2$).

Mathematically, this is a linear PDE (partial differential equation). These type of equations are relatively simple to study, and in mathematics studying a PDE is mostly investigating its well-posedness, i.e. proving that given suitable initial data (in a functional space with some structure) the solution exists, is unique and belongs to the same space as the initial datum. If the well-posedness is proved for any time $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then we may say the equation is globally well-posed.

From physical considerations, we know very well the functional space where $\psi$ should live, since $\lvert \psi\rvert^2$ is a probability distribution and its integral has to be finite (actually one). The functions that have squared modulus integrable are called square integrable, and their (Hilbert) space is denoted by $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Therefore, to give meaning to the Schrödinger equation we may investigate its global well-posedness on $L^2$. This is mathematically very natural, and it turns out that given $\psi\in L^2$, $e^{it\Delta}\psi$ is the solution of the Schrödinger equation, and again belongs to $L^2$.

But the physicists, motivated by the study of waves, had in mind a set of explicit solutions to the Schrödinger equation above: anything of the form
$$\psi_k(t,x)=ae^{-i(k^2t+kx)}+be^{-i(k^2t-kx)}\; ,\; k\in\mathbb{R}$$
solves the equation, but ***it is not a solution in $L^2$*** (it is actually a solution in $L^\infty$). They call this object, with an analogy to electromagnetism, plane wave.

As I said, plane waves are not suitable for quantum mechanics, since they are not square integrable (in the whole $\mathbb{R}^d$). How to relate them to $L^2$ objects, that are well-defined?

With the Fourier transform: the Fourier transform is a unitary operator on $L^2$ and if you write $e^{it\Delta}\psi$ as the transform of its Fourier transform you obtain
$$\psi(t,x)=e^{it\Delta}\psi=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-ik^2t}e^{ikx}\hat{\psi}(k)dk\; ,$$
where $\hat{\psi}(k)\in L^2$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(0,x)$, the initial time wavefunction. The physicists interpret the last member as a ***wavepacket***, i.e. a "superposition", mediated by a square-integrable function, of plane waves. But mathematically, it is just the unique solution of the Schrödinger equation in $L^2$ written in Fourier components.

Answer (score 0):

The wave packet concept is also related to the inability of plane wave to describe the communication of information. The plane wave wave occupies the whole space, whereas the wave packet is localised at some position with certain distribution. This is intimately related to the group velocity and phase velocity that are also used in classical optics. To propagate the information with certain speed one also needs to make an optical wave packet in classics. In QM the wave packet is a particle which propagates with the group speed of wave packet. The plane wave is also a solution of equation of motion in QM, but one needs a packet to relate this waves to an electron for example.